# Why I get error when I try to install pyaudio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pyaudio

The first error whas Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is not installed and I fixed it... Now when I try to install pyaudio I get another error. (I've Windows 10)

I've installed all visual studio's packages... I tried also to use wheel installation but it says that wheel is not supported on this platform

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r8s
c6ih0\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Hp\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp\pip-record-zm1aoh_y\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\venv\include\site\python3.7\pyaudio:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Users\Hp\PycharmPro
jects\Jarvis\venv\include -IC:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visua
l Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include" "-IC:\Program Files (
x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.1
8362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': ridefinizione macro
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: vedere la precedente definizione di 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Non Š possibile aprire il file inclusione: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.22.27905\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: You are building `pyaudio` from source but the compiler can't find the file `portaudio.h` which it needs. Try to find it on your system and add its location to your computer's INCLUDE path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [docs](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/):

> To build PyAudio from source, you will also need to build PortAudio v19

That being said and seeing your error message: `'portaudio.h': No such file or directory error`, I think you  have not installed this dependency.

The key part here is that `PyAudio` only provides python bindings to the `Portaudio` library, but does not include the library itself, unless you install using a `.whl`, but these are not available for `python 3.7`. Again, from the docs (emphasis mine):

> `pip` will fetch and install `PyAudio` wheels (prepackaged binaries). Currently, there are wheels compatible with the official distributions of **Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6**. For those versions, both 32-bit and 64-bit wheels are available.

So your solution is to either download and install the missing library, or move to a python version for which there are pre built wheels that include `Portaudio`